# Keep same view(s) in multiple controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

I'm currently developing an app that has three buttons at the bottom of the layout (for customization reasons I couldn't use TabBar Controller or Segmented Control).

When I click one of these buttons, a new view should show up and inherite the buttons bar, along with its state (buttons can be in selected or unselected state).

I'm  completely new to iOS development, so I tried following this guide (http://www.thinkandbuild.it/working-with-custom-container-view-controllers/), but problem is when I click a button, child view doesn't show up.

ContainerViewController.h

```
@interface ContainerViewController : UIViewController

        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *firstButton;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *secondButton;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *thirdButton;
        @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *detailView;

        - (IBAction)click:(id)sender;

    @end
```

ContainerViewController.m

```
#import "ContainerViewController.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface ContainerViewController ()
@property UIContainerViewController  *currentDetailContainerViewController;
@end

@implementation ContainerViewController
@synthesize firstButton, secondButton, thirdButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
    // switch buttons state
    // ...

    [self addDetailController:sender];
}

- (void)presentDetailController:(UIContainerViewController*)detailVC{

    //0. Remove the current Detail View Controller showed
    if(self.currentDetailContainerViewController){
        [self removeCurrentDetailContainerViewController];
    }

    //1. Add the detail controller as child of the container
    [self addChildContainerViewController:detailVC];

    //2. Define the detail controller's view size
    detailVC.view.frame = [self frameForDetailController];

    //3. Add the Detail controller's view to the Container's detail view and save a reference to the detail View Controller
    [self.detailView addSubview:detailVC.view];
    self.currentDetailContainerViewController = detailVC;

    //4. Complete the add flow calling the function didMoveToParentContainerViewController
    [detailVC didMoveToParentContainerViewController:self];

}


- (void)removeCurrentDetailContainerViewController{

    //1. Call the willMoveToParentContainerViewController with nil
    //   This is the last method where your detailContainerViewController can perform some operations before neing removed
    [self.currentDetailContainerViewController willMoveToParentContainerViewController:nil];

    //2. Remove the DetailContainerViewController's view from the Container
    [self.currentDetailContainerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

    //3. Update the hierarchy"
    //   Automatically the method didMoveToParentContainerViewController: will be called on the detailContainerViewController)
    [self.currentDetailContainerViewController removeFromParentContainerViewController];
}

- (CGRect)frameForDetailController{
    CGRect detailFrame = self.detailView.bounds;

    return detailFrame;
}

- (void)addDetailController:(id)sender {
    FirstViewController *detailVC = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithString:@"First view"];

    [self presentDetailController:detailVC];

}




@end
```

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ContainerViewController;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)string;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController (){
    NSString *text;
}
@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)string {
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        text = string;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.label.text = text;

}


@end
```

Comment: How about this tab bar [MHTabBarController](https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController). totally customizable from content to tabbars, you can have anything as tab bar view.

Comment: I need to select multiple tabs. For example, Tab 1 and Tab 2 share the same view (like a segmented control) but I'm able to select both (or one of them, or none), in order to "filter" something on the view. Tab 3, instead, should be indipendent. Do you know if that's possible with the solution you suggested?

Comment: Do any of the buttons show highlighting when you click them? If they are all unclickable, that's usually a sign that they are outside the bounds of their superview, so this could be a problem with your constraints (often, this problem is because the superview has zero size).

Comment: I updated the question: actually the buttons remain clickable, but child view never shows up.